# How can I use Dojox with an overall theme (disable deviceTheme)?

Tags: android, themes, ibm-mobilefirst, dojo

How can I use Dojox with an overall theme?

When I run my device on an android device, my app looks completely different.
The font-color is white when it needs to be black. (because it uses the 'Holodark' theme from Android).

How can I set Dojox that it only uses the common Css?

Answer (score 1):

For Worklight V6, in your main HTML file, remove:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dojox/mobile/deviceTheme.js"></script>
```

and in its place put:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dojox/mobile/themes/iphone/iphone.css">
```

(or pick one of the others as your fixed theme)

If you are on Worklight V5, you need to remove "dojox/mobile/deviceTheme" from the require() in your main javascript file, and add the css link above to the main HTML

Comment: If I remove "deviceTheme.js", my views won't render.

Comment: Make sure that your app is successfully loading dojox/mobile/themes/iphone/iphone.css